# Strange c++ linker error

Tags: c++, linker

I have an executable which executes tests using google test lib.

My test.exe links to:

- Core
- gtest

Now, in the Core library I have a shared pointer (template) class. As I understand it, template classes do not require dllexport/import decorators (confirmed by adding it in and still had no luck) on the class definition.

SharedPointer.h

```
template<typename T>
struct TSharedPtr
{
private:
    T* Ptr = nullptr;       /**< Native pointer to data */
    RefCounter* Counter = nullptr;      /**< Refernce counter to data */
    uint32 GetRefCount() const
    {
        return Counter->GetCount();
    }
};
```

The linker error is with RefCounter->GetCount(), it is saying that the function cannot be found.

Here is my RefCounter.h

```
#pragma once
#include "CoreAPI.h"
class CORE_API RefCounter
{
private:
    uint32 Count = 0;
public:
    inline void AddRef() { Count++; }
    inline uint32 RemoveRef() { return --Count;}
    inline uint32 GetCount() { return Count; }
};
```

As you can see I've added the CORE_API (dllimport/export) decerator but to no avail I am getting the following linker errors:

```
> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall Core::RefCounter::RefCounter(void)" (__imp_??0RefCounter@Core@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Core::TSharedPtr<class TestClass>::TSharedPtr<class TestClass>(class TestClass *)" (??0?$TSharedPtr@VTestClass@@@Core@@QAE@PAVTestClass@@@Z) RunTests    C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Project\RunTests\TSharedPtrTests.obj    1   

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall Core::RefCounter::AddRef(void)" (__imp_?AddRef@RefCounter@Core@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Core::TSharedPtr<class TestClass>::TSharedPtr<class TestClass>(struct Core::TSharedPtr<class TestClass> const &)" (??0?$TSharedPtr@VTestClass@@@Core@@QAE@ABU01@@Z)    RunTests    C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Project\RunTests\TSharedPtrTests.obj    1   

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: unsigned int __thiscall Core::RefCounter::RemoveRef(void)" (__imp_?RemoveRef@RefCounter@Core@@QAEIXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Core::TSharedPtr<class TestClass>::~TSharedPtr<class TestClass>(void)" (??1?$TSharedPtr@VTestClass@@@Core@@QAE@XZ)   RunTests    C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Project\RunTests\TSharedPtrTests.obj    1   

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: unsigned int __thiscall Core::RefCounter::GetCount(void)" (__imp_?GetCount@RefCounter@Core@@QAEIXZ) referenced in function "public: unsigned int __thiscall Core::TSharedPtr<class TestClass>::GetRefCount(void)const " (?GetRefCount@?$TSharedPtr@VTestClass@@@Core@@QBEIXZ) RunTests    C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Project\RunTests\TSharedPtrTests.obj    1   

> Error LNK1120 4 unresolved externals  RunTests    C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Binaries\Windows\Runtime\Editor\Debug\RunTests.exe  1
```

Note:: If I remove "CORE_API" from RefCounter, it compiles and runs. But I thought dllimport/export decorators were required for concrete classes build into a DLL. Could anyone explain why this is the case as it doesn't make much sense to me...

Comment: Wasn't this question already posted yesteday? The solution was to remove CORE_API.

Comment: Not by me? I posted it on Reddit but had no response, I want to know why removing CORE_API fixed it as it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Maybe I have seen it on reddit. It would have been better to ask the real question directly. Now your modified question is beyond page 5 and no one will see it.